# Indicator Function

Tags: probability, notation, indicator-function

Here is  an excerpt from "All of Statistics" by Larry Wasserman (page 23):

> Given an event A, define the indicator function of A by
>
> $$ I_{A}(\omega)= \color{Red}{I(\omega \in A)} =\begin{cases}  1 &
>  \text{ if } \omega \in A \\   0 & \text{ if } \omega \notin A 
>  \end{cases} $$

I am not convinced, referring to term colored red, with the notation here. Since this is a widely referred text, I would like to know that whether this is a typo or I am missing something here.

Comment: @Tim: I can't follow the significance of '>' and '<'. Please explain.

Comment: Sorry, something strange happen while saving edit. Those signs shouldn't be there - my edit was only to highlight the quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no suggestion there's a typo; it looks reasonably straightforward to me.

I'd informally read it left to right as something like:

"Define the function $I_A(\omega)$ -- an indicator of $(\omega\in A)$ -- which takes the value $1$ when $\omega\in A$ and $0$ otherwise."

Comment: (+1) This is a most standard notation that indicates whether or not the measurable event "$\omega\in A$" has occurred.