# What does 1 with an inequality in the subscript mean?

Tags: notation, indicator-function

I have not seen the following notation before (the 1 with a subscript in the density):

> Consider the problem of sampling from the truncated normal
>   distribution $\mathcal{N}_t (\mu, 1, a)$, given by the random variable $X ∼ \mathcal{N} (\mu, 1)$ conditional on the event $\{X \geq a\}$. Its density is proportional to
>
> $$f(x) \propto \mathrm{exp}\{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\}1_{x \geq a}$$

What exactly does that mean?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145945/indicator-function and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239055. For the use of the indicator function in describing truncated distributions see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330771, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/308228/919, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/77961/919.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$\mathbb{1}_{x\ge a}$ is an indicator function, that is equal to $1$ when $x\ge a$ and zero otherwise. Multiplying by it is a fancy, math way of saying that everything else is equal to zero. In this case, it says that only cases greater or equal to $a$ can be observed.

Comment: Thank you - that makes perfect sense with how i'd understood the truncated distribution.

Comment: @jm22b see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/198481/35989 for more details on truncation and censoring

Answer (score 7):

The I in the formula is the indicator function. In this case it equals 1 when x>=a and zero otherwise.

Comment: Note that this is an example of a normal distribution truncated on the left. The normal distribution can also be truncated on the right or on both side. These can also be specified using the indicator function.